# Rails - validates_associated on two has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to validate/prevent a not existing FK before try to save the model.

```
class Turma < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :turma_professor
    has_many :professores, through: :turma_professor
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :professores
end

class TurmaProfessor < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :turma
    belongs_to :professor
end

class Professor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :turma_professor
    has_many :turma, :through => :turma_professor
end
```

I select a `Professor`, alter the `Professor.id` and save. Rails shows me the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Professor with id=123 [WHERE "pessoas"."tipo" = 1])
```

Have some way to validate this fake id on the ActiveModel's validates methods?

Comment: Can you please paste the code which change the id

Comment: I did do it manually. Alter the input  `turma[professor_ids][]` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add validation to **turma.rb**.

**PREFEQUISITE:**

I guess your controller is like below.

```
# Not raise exception because professore_ids 1, 3 exist.
Turma.new(professore_ids: [1, 3])
  Professor Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "professors".* FROM "professors" WHERE "professors"."id" IN (1, 3)
=> #<Turma id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

# Raise exception because professore_id 4 doesn't exist.
Turma.new(professore_ids: [1, 4])
  Professor Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "professors".* FROM "professors" WHERE "professors"."id" IN (1, 4)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all Professors with 'id': (1, 4) (found 1 results, but was looking for 2)
```

So that you should catch `ActiveRecordd::RecordNotFound` in your `Turma` model.

**HOW TO ADD VALIDATEION:**

```
class Turma < ActiveRecord::Base
  # declear not_found_professor_ids flag
  attr_reader :not_found_professor_ids

  has_many :turma_professor
  has_many :professores, through: :turma_professor, source: :professor
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :professores

  # validation
  validates :not_found_professor_ids, inclusion: { in: [true], message: "don't found" }

  def professore_ids=(ids)
    super(ids)
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    # set flag
    self.not_found_professor_ids = true
  end
end
```

and use it.

```
turma = Turma.new(professore_ids: [1,4])
turma.valid? #=> false
turma.errors.full_messages #=> ["Not found professor ids don't found"]
```

Comment: its works :), but I had to change `super(ids)`  to `professor_ids = ids`. A another question, how can I add a locacel for `not_found_professor_ids`?

Comment: What does **how can I add a locacel for not_found_professor_ids** mean? Do you wanna show **not_found_professor_ids** in your view?

Comment: Sorry, typed it wrong, should be "locale". Yes, show the messagem on the view, like the anothers erros like `blank`, `taken`, `inclusion`. How should be the translate this message?

Comment: ok, sorry, my fault. Reading it again I understand that `not_found_professor_ids` is now a `Turma`'s attribute, so the translate works in the same way of other attribues

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem for exactly that:https://github.com/perfectline/validates_existence

Use `validates: :turma, existence: true` on your join model, and everything should work as expected.

You might also want to add `dependent: destroy` somewhere to your associations (or else you can end up with invalid associations pointing to already deleted items), and maybe use the newly added `add_foreign_key` migration statement to guarantee the linking integrity on the database level.

Comment: Is there support for Rails 4?

Comment: @hebergentilin Yes, but there are some deprecation warnings in 4.2 (The issue seems to be easily fixable.)

Comment: it didn't work. The rails peform a select looking up the  `professor` with the fake id. In this moment is throw a `NotFoundException`, neither reach out the `validates_existence`.